# How to declare a variable in mvc view with razor to have html atribute class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-views

I want to display a text with 2 links inside the text in MVC view!
    The text link are dynamic from server side and looks like this in controller:

```
Model.Message = "You have used up all your credits for this month (see  your credit balance {FirstLink}). You can buy credits {SecondLink}";
```

In view I have something like this

```
@{
var messageToShow = @Model.Message;

var newText = Html.ActionLink(Model.LinkText, Model.LinkAction, Model.LinkController, Model.LinkRouteValues).ToString();

var link = Html.ActionLink(Model.SecondLinkText, Model.SecondLinkAction, Model.SecondLinkController, Model.LinkRouteValues).ToString();

}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LinkText))
{
    messageToShow = messageToShow.Replace("{FirstLink}", newText);
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SecondLinkText))
{
    messageToShow = messageToShow.Replace("{SecondLink}", link);
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]

@Html.Raw(messageToShow)
```

This is working like it is but I have to add the class to it like this

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.SecondLinkText, Model.SecondLinkAction, Model.SecondLinkController, Model.LinkRouteValues, new { @class = "link" })
```

When adding the ,new{ @class = "link"} I got syntax error since the closing } is badly interpreted by razor engine.

Can you help out or maybe suggest a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve the syntax error, your view model would need to include a property for the html attributes, either

```
public IDictionary<string, object> LinkAttributeValues { get; set; }
```

if `LinkRouteValues` is typeof `RouteValueDictionary`, or

```
public object LinkAttributeValues { get; set; }
```

if `LinkRouteValues` is typeof `object`

And then you code becomes

```
Html.ActionLink(Model.SecondLinkText, Model.SecondLinkAction, 
    Model.SecondLinkController, Model.LinkRouteValues, Model.LinkAttributeValues)
```

Note that both your `@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model....))` lines so of code are pointless since if either `LinkText` or `SecondLinkText` were `null` or an empty string, the previous `Html.ActionLink(..)` lines of code would have thrown an exception.

One option would be to simply use

```
<span>You have used up all your credits for this month (see your credit balance</span>
@Html.ActionLink(Model.LinkText, Model.LinkAction, Model.LinkController, Model.LinkRouteValues, new { @class = "link" })
<span>). You can buy credits</span>
@Html.ActionLink(Model.SecondLinkText, Model.SecondLinkAction, Model.SecondLinkController, Model.LinkRouteValues, new { @class = "link" })
```

or if you want to set the message text in the controller, you could have 2 properties, say `string Message` and `string Message2` and use `<span>@Model.Message1</span>....`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix an '@' before the ActionLink when you're inside a code block. Remove that and I'm sure the syntax error will disappear.